# what does the following mean in each part of the type

Tags: c#, .net

The type looks like "example.exampletype1, example", what does each part mean?

Comment: Could you post some actual C# code where you see this?

Comment: Could you provide some context, i.e. an *actual* line of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`example` is the namespace, `exampletype1` is the type name and `example` (the one after the `,`) is the assembly name where this type is hosted. You can take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx) on MSDN about the grammar of fully qualified type names.